# Storing data points in a vector in a loop in R

Tags: r

I have a loop as written below:

```
Net_Sentiment_n = c()

for (i in 1:length(corpfinal)) {
  sentence = sentimentr::get_sentences(as.character(corpfinal[[i]][1]))
  sentence_sentiment_n[i] = sentimentr::sentiment(sentence[i], 
           lexicon::hash_sentiment_loughran_mcdonald, n.before = Inf, n.after = Inf)
   Net_Sentiment_n[i] = mean(sentence_sentiment_n$sentiment)
}
```

Here, the resultant Net_Sentiment_n is a vector

`corpfinal` is a corpus with length 797 (797 text files), also `corpfinal[[i]][1]` gives the text for each file (i.e. [1] for 1st text file and [2] for second and so on)

The sentence function extracts individual sentences from each file in the corpus and stores it as a list,for example, to get first sentence of the first text files it would `sentence[[1]][1]`, for second `sentence[[1]][2]` and so on

The `sentence_sentiment_n` is a function extract sentiment from these sentences for each individual text file.

And the `mean(sentence_sentiment_n)` gives the average (overall) sentiment for each text file (Averages across sentences).

I want to store the overall sentiment for each text file in the vector `Net_sentiment_n`, however currently I am only getting the sentiment of the last file when I run the loop.

As an example for corpus, please consider below:

text_1 = tm::PlainTextDocument("this is just an example.However it does serve a good purpose.","if this works, the overall text should also work.")

corp_test = tm::Corpus(tm::VectorSource(text_1))

Can someone please suggest on how to proceed.

Comment: I am sure that you will get help if you provide a minimal and reproducible example. You have initialised the vector `Net_Sentiment_n = c()`, but in the loop there is another vector `sentence_sentiment_n[i]` that is not initialised. Could it also be that your line `mean(sentence_sentiment_n$sentiment)` should be transformed to `mean(sentence_sentiment_n[i]$sentiment)`?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @MKR the sentiment function cannot be applied to a list

Comment: @RonakShah i think i have provided everything here except for the actual corpus. which i cannot because each text is really long. that's why i explained which form the corpus is.

Comment: added an example for corpus, hope it helps in suggesting some solutions

Comment: Still not sure how the example relates to the question. `tm::PlainTextDocument()' in your example produces 'content' and 'meta' sublist. Do you need it for the content (i.e. "this is just an example.However it does serve a good purpose.",) or for the meta (i.e. "if this works, the overall text should also work.")? I can kind of see what you want to do. You would like to end up with a vector that tells you the sentiment of each file. However, the example is not clear enough. Read the links that @RonakShah provided.

Comment: the said in the example to take corpus[[1]][1], which provides the content of the corpus. this is already specified in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Net_Sentiment_n = c()

for (i in 1:length(corpfinal)){

sentence = sentimentr::get_sentences(as.character(corpfinal[[i]][1]))

sentence_sentiment_n = sentimentr::sentiment(sentence,lexicon::hash_sentiment_loughran_mcdonald, n.before = 0, n.after = 1)

Net_Sentiment_n = mean(sentence_sentiment_n$sentiment)

}

needed a minor adjustment, works perfect now.